# Is there any way to avoid duplicates in android embed realmobject?

Tags: java, android, realm

My classes are like that,

**Product**

```
public class Product extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        String macAddress;
        String electronicNo;
        RealmList<MonthlyLog> monthlyLogs;

        public Product() {
        }
    }
```

**Monthly Log**

```
@RealmClass(embedded = true)
public class MonthlyLog extends RealmObject {
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private String consumption;

    public MonthlyLog() {
    }
}
```

I want to avoid duplicate records in monthly logs. I can't escape duplicate records as no primary key is given in embedded realm classes.
Is there a way to avoid saving duplicate records, other than giving up the embedded class logic and adding a primary key?

Comment: Can you tell us what would classify a log a being a 'duplicate' of another? And, btw, a primary key does not guarantee no duplicates; it only guarantee's no duplicate primary keys. You still could have two objects with the exact same data, other than the primary key.

Comment: By duplicate data I mean, for example, there is more than one consumption data for November of 2021. I don't want this situation. For this reason, I was creating a primary key from the month and day and dealing with it.

Comment: If the embedded object has a dateStamp like "2021-11" then it would be straightforward to filter for that within the objects and if one exists, do not save. Is there something more?

Comment: As far as I understand, you suggest that I check the incoming data to see if it exists in the database and then save it. I think I'll give up the embedded object logic and leave this job to realm with the primary key instead. Thanks for your recommendations.